# asp.net react returns index.html instead of json

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm kinda new to using react with asp.net and I seem to be having a routing problem.

What I'm trying to do is fetch data from a database and get it to the react component.
The data gets as far as the controller, where it's correctly logged in the console, but when I'm trying to fetch it in the react component, it returns index.html instead.

DatabaseController.cs

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class DatabaseController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    private readonly ILogger<DatabaseController> _logger;

    public DatabaseController(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<DatabaseController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        var xxx = configuration.GetValue<string>("xxx");
        var secretName = "xxx";

        var kvClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(xxx), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        var secret = kvClient.GetSecretAsync(secretName).Result;

        _connectionString = secret.Value.Value;
    }

    public class ApiKey
    {
        public string key_value { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpGet("GetApiKey")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetApiKey()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Connecting to database...");

        using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        _logger.LogInformation("Connected to database.");

        string query = "SELECT key_value FROM xxx";
        var result = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<string>(query);

        _logger.LogInformation("Retrieved data from database.");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Key: {result}");

        return Ok(new { apiKey = result });
    }
}
```

Map.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Map extends Component {
    static displayName = Map.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { apiKey: null };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("api/Database/GetApiKey")
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ apiKey: data });
            });
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.apiKey}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Azure.Core.Diagnostics;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using AzureEventSourceListener listener = AzureEventSourceListener.CreateConsoleLogger();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("xxx"));
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
builder.Services.AddScoped<DatabaseController>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// ...

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dbController = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseController>();
    await dbController.GetApiKey();
}

// ...

app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


app.Run();
```

Comment: Is React's routing set up correctly? Are there any error messages?